# Mock function use two times/same name

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest

I have a function to test that calls the same function twice, but this function returns two different data. I need to create a mock for the first variable and then for the second, I have a solution but it doesn't work in some cases. I want to be able to mock the api_result_first variable and the api_result_second variable which uses api_call().

Do you have an idea?

My code :

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import random 

def api_call():
  time.sleep(2)
  return random.randint(0,9)

def slow_function():
   api_result_first = api_call()
   api_result_second = api_call()
   result = api_result_first + api_result_second
   return result
```

My Pystest :

```
from a import *
import pytest

# https://changhsinlee.com/pytest-mock/

def test_aa(mocker):
    mocker.patch("a.api_call", return_value="ok")
    value = slow_function()
    assert isinstance(value, int)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `side_effects` to provide a sequence of return values to use.

```
def test_aa(mocker):
    mocker.patch("a.api_call", side_effects=[3, 5])
    value = slow_function()
    assert value == 8
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect !

Comment: I tested and on my side and is not works. The mock returns me this kind of object: <MagicMock name='api_call().__add__()' id='2397105397088'>. Is it possible to assign for each variable name a mocker value?

Comment: This worked for me, but the parameter name is `side_effect` not `side_effects`.